# Why is GNAT (via GCC 4.7) a prerequisite for building GCC?

Tags: gcc, gnat

In the [GCC installation prerequisites page](https://gcc.gnu.org/install/prerequisites.html), it says:

> GNAT
>
> In order to build GNAT, the Ada compiler, you need a working GNAT compiler (GCC version 4.7 or later).

Questions:

1. Is it a bit strange for GCC to require an Ada compiler, when it already requires a C++ compiler? I mean, GCC is not written in Ada AFAICR.
2. This means that if I have a non-GNU C/C++ compiler, or a pre-4.7 GCC, I can't install a newer GCC directly. And this means I can't install a newer GCC on a full-blown Linux distribution from, say, 7-8 years ago or so - even if it had the latest and greatest packages, including possibly even GNAT.

I'm not asking this as a rant, what I'm trying to understand is what the cause is, in terms of the structure of the code of GCC or dependent libraries, that's behind this requirement.

Comment: *"GCC is not written in Ada"* - but the next sentence explains *"since the Ada front end is written in Ada and uses some GNAT-specific extensions"*. And it is only a prerequisite for building GNAT, not the whole gcc.

Comment: @user7860670: 1. So, I can build GCC without Ada support, without gnat? 2. Those extensions are not supported in pre-GCC-4.7 gnat? 3. The C and C++ parts of GCC supposedly don't use GCC-specific extensions; does the Ada front end really need them?

Comment: If i remember correctly, GNAT is built only if you explicitly enable Ada language. Note sure about extensions.

Comment: Take a look at the `--enable-languages` option to `configure`, see https://gcc.gnu.org/install/configure.html.  This confirms that Ada support (i.e. GNAT) is not built by default, and so if you don't care about Ada you can disregard the whole issue.  Try it and see.